# passing parameters and return values in shell

Tags: shell, parameters, return-value

I have written a function named 'connectTo' which takes paramaters named 'options' and it should return some string by echoing before return.

```
 connectTo ${options}
```

this works i.e arguments get passed in this but when i write

```
str=$(connectTo ${options})
```

then connectTo is working as if no arguments were passed>
I am new to shell scripting and obviously doing something wrong but what?
(remember i need a string to be returned from fuction which cannot be a global variable)

```
function connectTo(){
    local flag=false
    local str=""
    for i in $@; do
            if [ "$flag" = true ]; then
                    str=$i
                    flag=false
            elif [[ "$i" = "--foo" || "$i" = "-f" ]]; then
                    flag=true
            fi
            echo "$i"
    done;
    if [ "$str" = "" ]; then
            echo ""
            return 0
    fi
    echo "found"
    return 0
}
```

In case of `connectTo ${options}` the arguments get printed while in second case they don't

Answer (score 0):

you should not use '$' sign while assigning a variable. so it should be
str =connectTo [value_of_argument]

$ is used to access the value of variable.